# How to extend height of DataGrid based on the height of another?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I’d like to be able have equal heights of two `DataGrid`s based on the `DataGrid` that have more data and become higher because of it. In other words, I’d like to have two `DataGrid`s be the same in heights regardless data input. I have one row and few columns where one `DataGrid` takes one column and another `DataGrid` takes another column. In case, one of `DataGrid` gets more input then it extends taller. I want another `DataGrid` to be the same tall with empty space below. I am wondering how I can make it work. Any `DataGrid` should expand automatically based on the height of taller `DataGrid`. Any ideas are highly appreciated!

Below is sample XAML:

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="DataGridExpand.MainWindow"
x:Name="Window"
Title="MainWindow"
Width="640" Height="480">

<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="Info" XPath="Info/Values">
          <x:XData> 
            <Info xmlns="">
              <Values Name="Value1" />
              <Values Name="Value2"  />
              <Values Name="Value3" />
              <Values Name="Value4" />
              <Values Name="Value5"  />
              <Values Name="Value6"  />
              <Values Name="Value7"  />
              <Values Name="Value8"  />
              <Values Name="Value9"  />
            </Info>
          </x:XData>
    </XmlDataProvider>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="Info2" XPath="Info2/Values2">
          <x:XData> 
            <Info2 xmlns="">
              <Values2 Name="Value1" />
              <Values2 Name="Value2"  />
              <Values2 Name="Value3" />
              <Values2 Name="Value4" />
              <Values2 Name="Value5" />
            </Info2>
          </x:XData>
    </XmlDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="10" > 
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="49*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="49*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Padding="10" BorderBrush="Black" Background="#FFD2D2D2">
        <DataGrid x:Name="Main" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/Info2/Values2}"
            DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Info2}}" Margin="10">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding XPath=@Name}" Foreground="#FF6E6E6E" Width="160" />   
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Border>
    <GridSplitter x:Name="GridSplitter" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1" />
    <Border Grid.Column="2" Padding="10" BorderBrush="Black" Background="#FFD2D2D2">
        <DataGrid x:Name="Main1" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="10"
            ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/Info/Values}" 
            DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Info}}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding XPath=@Name}" Foreground="#FF6E6E6E" Width="160" />   
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You can try this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30131363/grid-with-datagrid-resizing-in-wpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you need to have both `DataGrid`s to have the exactly same height? Try setting the `MinimumHeight` of one `DataGrid` to the `ActualHeight` of the other and vice versa. This may do the trick:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Main" 
    MinHeight="{Binding ElementName=Main1,Path=ActualHeight}"
    ...

<DataGrid x:Name="Main1" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    MinHeight="{Binding ElementName=Main,Path=ActualHeight}"
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for looking my thread. I solved that problem in a different way. I changed the layout of the grids that contain datagrinds which will allow to extended the height automatically. Datagrid is capable of doing it by default. Thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

You can put both `DataGrids` into a `Grid` with one row each, use `SharedSizeGroup` to have them sync. Set `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope` for a parent of both grids.

e.g. something like this

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="10" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    ...
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        ...
        <DataGrid .../> <!-- DataGrid 1 -->
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        ...
        <DataGrid .../> <!-- DataGrid 2 -->
    </Grid>
    ...
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thak you for your help. In my case, I can have only one grid. It looks like I cannot implement this technique. Any ideas?

Comment: I need the height of datagrid because I might have other elements in that row on top of datagrid. As a result, I need the datagrid to be extended to the bottom of the row because if other column has taller datagrid it will not be as tall as another datagrid. Both datgrid has be be the same heights.

Comment: I cannot visualize what you mean, a diagram would be helpful. Also, shouldn't you be able to handle pretty much every setting just by including/excluding specific elements in/from the shared-size-grid?

Comment: If you copy and paste the code I provided above into WPF project, then you will find two datagrids there. One of them shorter than another. I need the one that is shorter to be extended to the bottom and having white space for empty area to make it look the same in height as another one. This way both datagrids will be the same in heights.

Comment: This might be bit more difficult than expected; and i cannot help you with that right now...

Comment: Thank you for looking anyway.